# What is the life expectency of structs when returned from method and passed as parameters?

Tags: c#, .net, clr

I'll try to make a little more sense of this question with an example:

I have a struct:

```
struct RefStruct
{
   public object token;
   public object item;
}
```

and i have a method the returns that struct:

```
RefStruct createItem() {... }
```

Let's assume that 'createItem' generates an item and a token, where said token contains information usable by 'item' and 'item' referencing the same token internally via a WeakReference.

Now if i call this code (assuming 'doSomething' handles an Item and requires token to be alive):

```
{
   ...
   doSomething(createItem().item);
   ...
}
```

-Please notice that the call recieves 'item' and not the entire struct.

Is is guaranteed that the resulting RefStruct retured by 'createItem' is kept in memory during the call to 'doSomething'? or is the reference being discarded by the CLR and only item is now referenced (allowing the temporary struct to be GCed)?

hope this makes sense enough ;p

Comment: If the `token` isn't reachable except through the struct, why would you need it to stay alive? (Correct me if my premise is wrong, but then I still don't understand why you're concerned about `token` becoming GC'd)

Comment: You probably shouldn't be using a struct.

Comment: @delnan This is part of a Cache system, and as 'token' in the strcut is a strong reference, there are other WeakReferences, while token is not collected it is KNOWN that the cached item is needed and should not be removed from the cache

Answer (score 11, accepted):

> Let's assume that 'createItem' generates an item and a token, where said token is required to stay alive (i.e not GCed) for 'item' to be valid.

**Your design is fundamentally broken.** If the token must be alive for the item to be valid then the item should store a reference to the token.

Fix your design. Either decouple the validity of the item from the lifetime of the token, or make the item hold on to the token, or make a third thing that holds on to them both. (And then keep the third thing alive.)

> Is it guaranteed that the resulting RefStruct retured by 'createItem' is kept in memory during the call to 'doSomething'?

**Absolutely not.** The garbage collector is within its rights to collect token not only *before the call to DoSomething* but in fact *before CreateItem returns*. The garbage collector is allowed to look *arbitrarily far into the future* and predict the future behaviour of the program. If it can determine through analysis that the token object is *never* accessed then it is allowed to free it *at the moment after it is created*.

Whether it actually does so in any implementation of the CLR is an implementation detail, subject to change.

> If I store the result of 'CreateItem' to a temp struct, and pass the 'item' property to 'doSomething' is the optimizer still allowed to free the token early?

Yes. The jit compiler is perfectly within its rights to determine that the token field of the struct that is now promoted to be a local variable is never accessed; it is well within its rights to garbage collect the token reference.

The *struct storage* itself will not be reclaimed early; you could, for example, later *write* to the token field portion of the local storage. But the memory for the object referenced by the *token field* can be reclaimed at any time.

> Will using volatile on the 'token' member change this?

No. Volatile fields have acquire and release semantics on writes and reads; that has nothing whatsoever to do with the lifetime of the field.

Can you explain why would you suppose that making the field volatile would change its lifetime? I am always interested to learn why people believe bizarre things.

> I would like to guarantee that as long as i hold the token, it will not be GCed, to avoid GC during the operation of 'doSomething'

Now we come to the actual problem. So far you've been asking questions about how drill motors work instead of asking about the kind of hole you'd like to drill. If the question is "how do I keep alive this dead thing?" the answer to that is simple.  **Call [GC.KeepAlive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.gc.keepalive.aspx).** That's what it's for.

As the documentation clearly states:

> The purpose of the KeepAlive method is to ensure the existence of a reference to an object that is at risk of being prematurely reclaimed by the garbage collector.

Now, a reasonable question at this point is "but if the token is in danger of being collected, then how is it possible that someone might be using it to improve the efficiency of the item?"  You answer that question in this comment:

> This is part of a cache system, and as 'token' in the strcut is a strong reference, there are other WeakReferences, while token is not collected it is known that the cached item is needed and should not be removed from the cache

**You are putting the garbage collector in charge of enforcing your caching policy**. The garbage collector was not designed to have good behaviour for *your* scenario; the garbage collector was designed to have good behaviours for the general problem of memory management in a general-purpose programming language.

I would think very hard before I put a lifetime management engine designed by one group of people to solve their general problem in charge of determining policy for a potentially completely different problem space. The fact that you are asking these sorts of questions is indicative that you need to build your own cache policy enforcement code rather than relying on the GC to do it for you in a manner not to your liking.

Supercat asks:

> Wouldn't the exact same problem occur if RefStruct were replaced with a class?

Yes. If you do, say, this:

```
Tuple<object, object> holder = CreateItem(...); 
DoSomething(holder.Item1);
```

Then again, the GC is perfectly within its rights to determine that "holder" is dead, and therefore holder.Item2 is dead, the moment that CreateItem is done executing. As I said, you'd have to keep "holder" -- the "third thing" -- alive. The GC is allowed broad lattitude in determine what is still alive.

Comment: @Eric: i wouldn't go as far as broken - Item can be used after 'token' is collected, but it is more expensive to do so as it acts as a cache for the item, thus users of the class can hold the token during certain operations to avoid re-calculation/generation of more complex content.

Comment: @AmitBenShahar: I would.  Although I haven't checked, I would suspect that the optimizer will get rid of the struct usage entirely

Comment: @SLaks,@Eric: Please see my answer to Eric - does this also means that if i store the result of 'CreateItem' to a temp struct, and pass the 'item' property to 'doSomething' the optimizer might still ignore it? will using volatile on the 'token' member fix this?

Comment: @AmitBenShahar: You said that the token is **required** to stay alive, not that *it is more efficient* if it does stay alive.

Comment: @AmitBenShahar: I've added answers to your updated questions.

Comment: @Eric: you are correct, i updated the question to better reflect the scenario, is this better? I would like to guarantee that as long as i hold the token, it will not be GCed, to avoid GC **during** the operation of 'doSomething'

Comment: Wouldn't the exact same problem occur if RefStruct were replaced with a class?  Although using a class would offer a choice as to whether to use GC.KeepAlive(theRefStructishObject) or GC.KeepAlive(theRefStructishObject.Token) in the absence of a GC.KeepAlive call I don't see that the class semantics would be any better than those of a struct.

Comment: I thought it **might** change something in the way the CLR handles the code as it relates to optimizations in regard to read/write from memory, I didn't **believe** it will solve it - i'm shopping for a solution.

Comment: @AmitBenShahar: I've added more answers to your further updated questions.

Comment: @Eric: you are correct in your assumption, and I do have my own internal caching logic, the goal here is to lengthen the lifetime of the cached info while there are references to it even when it's eligible for collection through my own logic. The system is a bit more complicated then I exposed in the question, as the full system description is long...

Comment: For discussion of when an object becomes eligible for collection, see also Raymond Chen's Blog Post: [When does an object become available for garbage collection](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/08/10/10048149.aspx).  Though normally you shouldn't care if token is collected out from under you; the garbage collector won't do that if it sees that you'll be using the token later...which it may not in some special cases like unmanaged objects and `unsafe`.

Comment: @EricLippert: how would you suggest to use GC.KeepAlive? please see my  comment to supercat, i would need to have a call to GC.KeepAlive after every call to 'doSomething' or any other methods that require to token to still be alive, calling within 'doSomething' is already too late, as the token can be collected before the method begins, right?

Comment: @EricLippert: I would be interested to pick your brain a little further in this regard, but don't think this is the proper place as it's more of a question of design of the cache system and strays from answering the above question, is that possible?

Comment: #EricLippert: I posted another very similar question, if you would be kind to take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10471817/does-holding-a-reference-to-an-object-will-keep-it-in-memory-if-the-reference-wi

Answer (score 5):

Structs don't have lifetimes; things that hold structs have lifetimes.
(although boxed structs do have lifetimes)

Your token can be GC'd immediately, since it's never referenced.

Comment: 'References' to structs? aren't structs ValueTypes and as such does not have references? (am i misunderstanding?)

Comment: I thought structs were value types and therefore don't have references?

Comment: @AmitBenShahar: value types are *copied by value*. But it is perfectly legal to take a reference to *the storage location that holds the value*.

Comment: @SLaks: It would be more clear to say "values of structs do not have lifetimes; storage locations which contain values of structs have lifetimes". In this particular case the storage location in question is extremely short-lived.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: What would be the best language-neutral terminology to describe what is passed to a routine that takes a "ref" parameter?  The term "reference" seems ambiguous, since it could also apply to the thing held by a class-type variable or field.  If I had my druthers, the things held by class-type variables would be called "Object IDs", but I doubt that will ever happen.  So what should the thing passed in the "ref" parameter be called?  A short-reference?  A ref-pointer?  Is there any reasonably-context-independent term?

Comment: @supercat: I struggle with this as well. Of course what is *actually* passed is a managed pointer to a variable, which can reasonably be called a "reference to storage". But from the point of view *of the C# language* the way you *use* the thing does not look like a reference at all; rather, it looks like you made a formal parameter into an alias to a variable accessible by the caller. I heartily wish we'd never chosen the keyword "ref"; if I had my druthers the "ref" keyword would be something like "alias" or "var" and "out" would be an attribute, not a keyword.

Comment: @Eric Lippert: The term "pass by reference" predates .net of course, and I think the "ref" keyword derives from that.  Still, if one was stuck with the term "object reference", another keyword might have been nice.  I dislike "out" as implemented, but mainly because I think "out" parameters should have had their value copied at exit (which would have allowed safe covariance); I also think there should have been compiler-enforced "in ref" parameters (which would avoid in many cases the need to copy read-only structures when passing to routines that wouldn't mutate them).

Answer (score 1):

No, the `RefStruct` could immediately GCed. Even doing this:

```
var rs = createItem();
doSomething(rs.item);
```

won't guarantee that the token is kept alive.

You could consider implementing `IDisposable` to make the dependency on the token a bit more explicit (in this case it is really recommended to use a class instead of a struct, see [this article on MSDN](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/abhinaba/archive/2005/10/05/477238.aspx))

```
class RefStruct : IDisposable
{
   public object token;
   public object item;

   public void Dispose() 
   { 
       Dispose(true);
       GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
   }

   protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
   {
        if (disposing)
        {
            token = null; // not necessary technically
        }
    }
}
```

And then use it:

```
using (var rs = createItem())
{
    doSomething(rs.Item);
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't the exact same problem exist with a class as with a struct in the absence of a "using" block?  And, wouldn't having the struct include a dummy "IDisposable.Dispose()" implementation allow the exact same fix?

Comment: @supercat You could make the struct disposable but that's generally not a good idea as it can easily result in unexpected behaviour.

Comment: There isn't much that an IDisposable.Dispose method would be able to do on a struct without causing weird behavior.  On the other hand, what I was proposing here would be a struct whose IDisposable.Dispose() method would do nothing except use GC.KeepAlive to make a dummy access to the Token field.  Reading a struct field is an operation whose semantics shouldn't be affected by boxing or any of the other evil things the system might do with structs.

Answer (score 1):

There may be some legitimate reasons to have RefStruct be a struct rather than a class, but regardless of whether it's a struct or a class, it's necessary to have a GC.KeepAlive call to ensure that the Token won't get collected while the other code is run on the Item.  I would suggest that one might want to, rather than exposing Item directly, have a generic DoSomethingWithItem method which accepts a delegate and a generic ref parameter, and which will call the supplied delegate on Item and then GC.KeepAlive the Token.  Having the generic method accept a generic ref parameter will, in most usage scenarios, allow one to use a static delegate and put any necessary input or output parameters in a value type, thus avoiding GC pressure.

Comment: This is an interesting idea! but, the token can still be GCed before the delegate method is called- as GC.KeepAlive only guards from beggining of the delegate routine to it's end, but not **before** it... right?

Comment: @Amit Ben Shahar: If there exists any possible execution path which would result in a GC.KeepAlive (or any other method) being called on an object without having to fetch the object from a WeakReference, the object will not be collected.  At the time the delegate is invoked, the execution engine will see that upcoming code is going to be calling GC.KeepAlive on Token, and will thus recognize that Token may not be legitimately GC'ed.

Comment: @Amit Ben Shahar: With regard to using GC.KeepAlive within the method, the issue isn't the invocation of the method, but rather the question of whether the system can identify any possible way by which a method could be called on Token by some means other than dereferencing a weak reference.  If the Token field of the struct, or the struct as a whole, will be used in any fashion after the method call, then it won't be collected.  The problem in the scenario posted is that once Item is evaluated, neither Token nor the struct as a whole will be used ever again.

Comment: @suportcat: Good point, I would then need to either start populating my code with calls to _GC.KeepAlive_ or find some other approach for managing the lifetime of my objects..

Comment: @Amit Bens: If a member of an object needs the containing object to be kept alive, then code which uses the member needs to do something to keep alive the object which contains it.  GC.KeepAlive is the most idiomatic thing to do in such a case.  Incidentally, WeakReference is not really well-suited to caching except in cases where one expects that persistent references will exist to objects as long as they are still of interest, tracking the continued existence of references would not be practical, and the cost of keeping objects cached excessively long is not great.